# Getting 'invalid ELF header' when running `docker-compose up` Django app?

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Django project I am trying to get running in Docker. Apologies in advance- I am very new to Docker and am probably doing something (things?) very wrong.

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /my-project
WORKDIR /my-project
ADD . /my-project/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Have the following .dockerignore file:

```
# Git
.git
.gitignore

# Docker
Dockerfile
.dockerignore

# Byte-complied / optimized / DLL files
**/__pycache__/
**/*.py[cod]

# Django migrations
**/migrations/*.py
!**/migrations/__init__.py

# Swap files
**/*.swp

# venv files
venv/
.env

# Sphinx build files
docs/_*/
```

Following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    container_name: my-project
    volumes:
      - .:/my-project
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, it runs until it hits the execution of `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`, when I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: /usr/local/bin/../lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0: invalid ELF header
```

What am I doing wrong?